# How to upload multiple file through angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload

This is my angular code.File upload is happening for a single file but for adding two other files is not happening.Could you please help me in this issue.Please help me I am badly stuck.

```
$scope.upload = function(){
            console.log("In upload function");
            console.log(deployTaskId);
            $scope.disableUpload = true;

            var uploadUrl = baseurl+"/"+encodeURIComponent(deployTaskId);
            alert(baseurl);
            console.log(uploadUrl);
            alert(uploadUrl);
            var file = $scope.deploy.myFile;
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: uploadUrl ,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-api-key': api_key
            },
            data: fd
            })
            .success(function(data, status){

            console.log("Success in uploading task file");
            $scope.disableUpload = false;
            console.log(data);
            console.log("upload Successful");
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
            console.log("Error in uploading task file");
            $scope.disableUpload = false;
            }); 
        };
```

This is my directive

```
task.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am personally using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload), this directive makes it easy to upload multiple files.

You can find samples on how to upload several files on the README.md.